# Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'channel'

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command(name="clear", alliases=["purge"])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear_messages(self, ctx, limit: typing.Optional[int] = 1):
    if 0 < limit <= 100:
        with ctx.channel.typing():
            await ctx.channel.purge(limit = limit)
            await ctx.message.delete()
```

I'm having issues with this code block specifically, where I get an error that 'str' has no attribut 'channel'. In other parts of my code (shown below) there is a similar idea, but the command passes. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.send('{}'.format(' '.join(args)))
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Is this a method, or just a plain old function? If the latter, then you need to remove the `self` arg.

Comment: `ctx` is a parameter, so whatever is calling this function is passing a string.

Answer (score 2):

There's two possible reasons:

- Your `clear_messages` isn't in a class, in which case you should remove the `self` argument.
- Your command is in a class, which would inply that you're using cogs. In this case, you should replace `@bot.command` to `@commands.command`

Judging by the code you gave, I'd say that the first reason may be the right one.

Comment: the first one was a solution, i removed "self" and it worked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Mr_Spaar !

the issue was the "self" argument, i removed it and it worked perfectly!